# Problems with HTTP/2 on nginx for Windows?

Tags: apache, nginx, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using nginx 1.17.10.1 Unicorn build from http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/ and Apache/2.4.43 build from Apachelounge on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Nginx serves static files and proxies Apache responses for PHP scripts. Everything was fine until recently.

Two times in a day without any distinct reason the websites stop responding. Memory/CPU/Network usages are ok. Apache starts logging like

`XX.XX.XX.XX 0ms [01/Jul/2020:05:05:20 -0700] "-" 408 - "-" "-"`

for each request.
Nginx log shows

`2020/07/01 06:04:54 [error] 11800#12192: *5002230 WSARecv() failed (10053: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) while reading response header from upstream, client: YY.YY.YY.YY, server: example.com, request: "GET /the/url/here HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8181/the/url/here", host: "example.com"`

Server reboot doesn't help. I can connect to the backend directly and it serves the response without any problem.

The only way I could resolve the problem was to switch HTTP/2 off in nginx configuration.

So what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Try changing the [keepalive_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout). Also if this system is within an organization managed by the IT department try checking if any new security protocol is imposed or if any new antivirus program is installed and does some scans on a regular basis.

Comment: @pebox11, no this machine is administered by me. I tried tweaking the keepalive, but it wasn't effective. Looking back in logs I saw a couple of 408 streaks on Apache, but they didn't last long. This time it just stuck and only turning http/2 off brought the websites back.